# Mocking aspects, testng and spring 4

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testng, aop

I have a very basic scenario where I just need to call a method which has an annotation.  This annotation simply calls an AspectJ advice.  I just need to make sure that the advice is being called, ideally via a mock verify.  Tests are being run using TestNG and mocking using Mockito.  Spring is version 4.

class under test

```
public class MyClassUT
{
    @MyAnnotation
    public myMethod...
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

test class

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringTestConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyClassUtTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    @InjectMocks private MyClassUT mine;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void init()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod()
    {
        mine...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the advice is being called and everything is OK, except for the fact that the advice class is instantiated once by spring and another time before calling the said method.  The instance being used is the latter which of course has no dependencies injected so it fails.  What I am trying to do is provide spring with a mock of my advice or at least inject a mock of the service it depends on and ask AspectJ to use that existing instance.

I have tried using factory methods for the advice, spring test configurations etc, however nothing seems to be working.  I have tried also with EnableAspectJautoproxy to no avail, instantiated the aspect with a @Bean annotation, also as a factory method - but nothing works well unfortunately.

*(It is also interesting to note that when I enable AspectJ in eclipse, the aspect test also run in maven and as far as I know, nothing changes in pom.xml.)*

So, **my question is:**

- How do I make the test use an instance of the aspect I or spring create so that when the method MyMethod is called, its dependencies are in place , or the mock version is used?
- [This problem is basically equivalent,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624341/spring-cannot-inject-a-mock-into-class-annotated-with-the-aspect-annotation%20this)  
  **but**
- How do I do this without a single line of XML config - I've seen using an apectOf factory method config being mentioned a lot, but I need a pure annotation solution, if possible;
- Works with TestNg not JUnit;

Thank you!